# Why does 'write()' take a const buffer while 'read()' doesn't?

Tags: c, unix

The signatures for read / write are below:

```
 ssize_t write(int fd, const void *buf, size_t count);

 ssize_t read(int fd, void *buf, size_t count);
```

Why doesn't `read()` also take a `const void *`? Does that mean it changes the value of `buf`?

Comment: What matters is that it changes the values that `buf` points to.  This makes sense: it is going to replace the contents of the buffer with the data read from the file.  `write`, on the other hand, doesn't need to change the buffer contents at all.

Comment: `read` writes the output into the space pointed to by `buf`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143262/what-is-the-difference-between-const-int-const-int-const-and-int-const/1143272#1143272

Comment: Thanks! I mistook the meaning of ```const```

Comment: @Max Darling Re "*I mistook the meaning of `const`*", `void * const buf` would mean `buf` itself can't be changed. And of course, `const void * const buf` can't change `buf` or that to which it points. /// Keep in mind that changing `buf` itself in the function has no effect on the caller because C always passes by value. So there's not much point in making parameters constant (but there's lots of value in making constant the buffer itself).

Answer (score 1):

Because `write()` won't change the contents of the buffer, but only write it to the file.

On the other hand, `read()` will change its buffer (from what's in the file) so it had better not be `const`.

General rule, what changes isn't `const`.